# R force argument missingness - R_MissingArg

Tags: r

There is an information about missing arguments in R internals: [Missingness](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Missingness).
I'm interested if there is a way to set (overwrite) argument of a function to `R_MissingArg` within that function?
Kind of:

```
f <- function(x){
    if(!missing(x)) message("x non missing")
    make_missing(x)
    if(missing(x)) message("x missing")
    invisible()
}
```

I understand it might not be a recommended way and I should probably use `x <- NULL` and `is.null(x)` instead of checking missingness.

Comment: Can you detail why you want to do this? I imagine it is because you are trying to pass it through to another function who's default you desire, so you want it to be missing (otherwise, if your just using it in the body of the function, you'd just do: isMissing = missing(x), and use that flag throughout. If you want to use the default for a subsequent call, then you'll probably need to manually setup the call using functions like, args()<-.

Comment: I see no context which would justify to use `make_missing(x)` instead of `x <- NULL` in production code. But I have some code to work on, which is quite long and there are multiple `missing(x)` checks, it would be convenient to not update all those checks to `is.null(x)` only to test some new thing.

Comment: Perhaps, you could use `x <- substitute()`: `f = function(x) { x = substitute(); missing(x) }; f(5)`

Comment: @alexis_laz so simple! it seems to work, post it as answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace "x" with `substitute()`:

```
var = substitute()
var
#Error: argument "var" is missing, with no default
```

And, although it's safer to just use `x = substitute()`, your `make_missing` could look something like:

```
make_missing = function(x) assign(deparse(substitute(x)), 
                                  substitute(), 
                                  envir = parent.frame())
```

And your "f":

```
f = function(x)
{
    if(missing(x)) message("missing") else message("not missing")

    make_missing(x)
    if(missing(x)) message("missing") else message("not missing")
}
f()
#missing
#missing
f(7)
#not missing
#missing
```